# Как создать объект доступный из @ClientEndpoint и @ServerEndpoint?

Tags: java, websocket

Я использую web-socket и необходимо получить объект который будет доступен и в `@ClientEndpoint` и `@ServerEndpoint` и желательно не статический. Возможно ли это как-то сделать?

Что-то вроде такого:

```
@ServerEndpoint("/chat")
public class ChatEndpoint {
    SameObject obj = ...;

    void somthisgToDoWithSameObject() {
        //...
    }
}

@ClientEndpoint
public class ChatClientEndpoint {
    private SameObject somehowGetSameObject() {
        //...
    }
}
```